# Can't connect MySQL in Docker from Spring-Boot Application with OpenJDK 8 in IDE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have ran this issue in different linux distros. I am using the same SpringBoot application and docker-compose file but I can't connect to dockerized MySQL from Intellij Community IDE when run/debug the application (and from DataGrip too).

My current setup:

- OpenSUSE Thumbleweed
- OpenJDK 1.8.0.292 version
- Docker 20.10.6-ce
- SpringBoot v2.1.8.RELEASE

My docker-compose yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  demo-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.18
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

SpringBoot error when I run application from IDE (character limit): https://controlc.com/4af02b4d

I am currently using OpenSUSE, I have ran this issue on Fedora Workstation 33 and 34. Java application not using SSL but gives SSL Handshake error while running without any issue on other distros such that Manjaro, Ubuntu, Pop_OS!.

I disabled firewall, commented `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` from `java.security` file, tried `spring.datasource.url` with `0.0.0.0:3306`,`127.0.0.1:3306`, `<docer-service-name>:3306`. I spend days on this issue, changed distros because of that, any help appreciated. I can give any required info.

(Updated)

JDBC Connection string is: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/database?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Comment: What library are you using to communicate with mysql? What jdbc connection string are you using.  Is spring boot also running in your container?  Have you verified mysql is running by connecting to it via any of the available third party clients? Why are you using docker compose version 2 instead of 3?

Comment: The application is using JPA, I updated my question with JDBC string. Docker-Compose file belong to the company I work for, because of that I didn't change it. I tried connect database with DataGrip application but it also gives the SSLHandshake error too.

Comment: If you cant connect with DataGrip then your issue is with the MySql server itself. You should check the output on startup to make sure it is actually starting.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. I can enter docker container itself and use mysql commands inside of it. I believe that this is a connection issue, like a firewall problem. But I am not using firewall, I check that docker listening 3306 port too.